# check if user likes a page with Laravel Socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I'm using Laravel Socialite to make users log in to my site. I've managed to do that and store the user's data.

But now i want to find out how i can check if that particular user (when logged in) has liked my facebook page.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socialite is a package that handles authentication using Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google, GitHub and Bitbucket. It does not have the ability to retrieve information regarding user likes.

You can use the [facebook-php-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4) inorder to get the pages that user has liked. The code below is from the [facebook graph api documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/) on how to get the pages that the user has liked.

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{user-id}/likes'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```